# Como puedo realizar dos funciones opuestas?

Tags: javascript, html

Buenas estoy intentando realizar dos funciones opuestas utilizando javascript; es decir, yo tengo 3 campos en un formulario, Tipo de Cambio, Costo en USD y Costo en ARS.

Mi primer función hace lo siguiente, si yo ingreso un tipo de cambio y un costo en usd automaticamente calcula el costo en ars.

Ahora quiero hacer lo mismo pero al reves, es decir si yo ingreso un tipo de cambio y un costo en ars que me calcule el costo en usd.

```js
 /*Mi primer Funcion*/
 
 function calcularCosts(){
    

    cost_repuestos = document.getElementById('cost_repuestos').value;
    change_type = document.getElementById('change_type').value;
    cost_repuestosARS = parseFloat(change_type) * parseFloat(cost_repuestos);
    document.getElementById('cost_repuestosARS').value = cost_repuestosARS;




  }

/*Mi segunda Funcion*/

  function costsInversa(){
    cost_repuestosARS = document.getElementById('cost_repuestosARS').value;
    change_type = document.getElementById('change_type').value;
    cost_repuestos =  parseFloat(cost_repuestosARS) / parseFloat(change_type);
    document.getElementById('cost_repuestos').value = cost_repuestos;
  }

  function Todas(){
    calcularCosts();
    costsInversa();
    
  }
```

```html
                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                      <label for="change_type">Tipo de cambio</label>
                      <input type="number"   step="00.01" name="change_type" id="change_type" onkeyup="Todas();"  class="form-control" >
                    </div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
                      <label for="cost_repuestos">Costo de repuestos (USD-O)</label>
                      <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="cost_repuestos" name="cost_repuestos" onkeyup="Todas();" class="form-control"  >
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                      <label for="cost_repuestosARS">Costo de repuestos (ARS)</label>
                      <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="cost_repuestosARS" name="cost_repuestosARS" onkeyup="Todas();" class="form-control"  >
                    </div>
```

Como pueden ver la primera funciona a la perfección, pero la segunda no porque esta interviniendo la función anterior. Hay alguna manera para que ambas funciones coexistan?

Comment: No ejecutes las funciones al mismo tiempo, sino con base en eventos, cuando se modifique un campo ejecutas una, cuando se modifique otro, ejecutas la inversa.

Comment: @Triby Como sería eso? Algún ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

creo que a lo que referia Triby es esto:
**HTML**

Tipo de cambio



Costo de repuestos (USD-O)

```
        <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label for="cost_repuestosARS">Costo de repuestos (ARS)</label>
            <input type="number" step="00.01" id="cost_repuestosARS" name="cost_repuestosARS" onblur="costsInversa();"
                class="form-control">
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
function calcularCosts(){        
    cost_repuestos = document.getElementById('cost_repuestos').value;
    change_type = document.getElementById('change_type').value;
    if(cost_repuestos ==""){
        cost_repuestos = 0;
    }
    if(change_type ==""){
        change_type = 0;
    }
    cost_repuestosARS = parseFloat(change_type) * parseFloat(cost_repuestos);
    document.getElementById('cost_repuestosARS').value = cost_repuestosARS;
  }

/*Mi segunda Funcion*/

function costsInversa(){
    cost_repuestosARS = document.getElementById('cost_repuestosARS').value;
    change_type = document.getElementById('change_type').value;
    if(cost_repuestos ==""){
        cost_repuestos = 0;
    }
    if(change_type ==""){
        change_type = 0;
    }
    cost_repuestos =  parseFloat(cost_repuestosARS) / parseFloat(change_type);
    document.getElementById('cost_repuestos').value = cost_repuestos;
}
```